# Python getting Strange Error

Tags: python

I keep getting this error `'list' object has no attribute 'priority'` and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is part of my code I cant show it all here as its my project:

```
    def Tree(self):

    while len(self.heap) > 0:
        leftChild= self.heap.pop(0)
        rightChild= self.heap.pop(0)
        a = leftChild.priority + rightChild.priority
        parent = [(leftChild.item + rightChild.item, a)]
        print parent
        #self.heap.insert(0, parent)
    #return self.heap[0]
```

So basically I have a priority queue list and I pass every elements to a heap which is a list. Then I take out each item by pop and each `leftChild` and `rightChild` should have, e.g.: `[("c", 0.1231)]` it runs fine and print the parent until I run the insert function which display the error message. Anyone has any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: `left` or `leftChild`? You really need to make your mind up.

Comment: its leftchild and rightchild

Comment: Where are `leftChild` and `rightChild` coming from?

Comment: Post all the relevant code and make sure it's indented correctly.  Without knowing how the children end up on self.heap, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Why do you expect an object like `[("c", 0.1231)]` to have a `priority` attribute? If you have a `Node` class or something that allows that kind of named attribute access, you need to actually construct an instance of it rather than just using lists and tuples.

Comment: I hve a priority queue class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's complaining about a list not having a `priority` attribute, then it's a safe bet that what's coming out of the heap (into `leftChild` for example) is a list rather than a "node" of some sort.

Make sure that you insert these nodes from the original list into your heap with something like:

```
self.heap.insert (myList[4])     # an item in the list
```

rather than:

```
self.heap.insert (myList[4:5])   # a sublist of the list.
```

You can try printing `type(leftChild)` to find out what actual type it is, as per the following transcript:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

>>> x1 = x[4]

>>> x2 = x[4:5]

>>> x1
5

>>> x2
[5]

>>> type(x1)
<type 'int'>

>>> type(x2)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: but i dont understand why it print the first parent then it says the error. So in parent the leftChild.priority is working but not in the insert function ?

Comment: when i type it in this came out
<type 'instance'>
<type 'list'>

Comment: @TommyNgo, well, there you have it. The things in the heap are lists rather than "nodes". You need to find the code that inserts them and fix that.